# How to add delete button on Touch event of dynamiclly generated view

Tags: android, image-processing

I am working on an application, In this I have number of dynamically generated textviews and Image views. Now I want when I touch on any of the dynamically generated view it should come to front and should appear a cross button on it to delete. I am stucking on this for long time please help me. Thanks in advance.
[image: I want to do like this]

Comment: I am making a collage of Images and Textviews . On button click I can add textview dynamically. And there  is touch event for each view. So I want to add small cross button with  the use of this ican delete the particular text or image

Answer (score 0):

`private Button button;
    onCreate(...) { //or any other method
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("touch me");
        LayoutContainer cont = (LayoutContainer)findViewById(R.id.container); //your id here
        cont.add(button); 
        button.addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
                  @Override
                  ... onClick(){
                  cont.removeView(button);//and again, not sure of method name
            }
        }); // like this, i'm not sure
    }`

Comment: can we use both click event and touch event at the same time on a view ??

Comment: How ?? I am unable to do so . Only one listener is working at a time.

Comment: `.addOnClickListener` and `.addOnTouchListener`
or just add `cont.removeView(button)` to your `onTouchListener`

Answer (score 0):

this code will add view into LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout layout2=(LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.relaGameZhaiGuoZi);
layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  
Button btn1=new Button(this);  
setContentView(layout2);  
Button btn2=new Button(this);  
btn1.setText("Button1");  
btn2.setText("Button2");  
layout2.addView(btn1);  
layout2.addView(btn2);
```

hope it helps

Comment: I know how to add view dynamically in layout, I have done it already but the problem is I have to add delete button on the dynamically generated view at touch event. Thanks for your reply

Comment: then you can add listener to the generated view and in the listener you can add delete button

Comment: yes I know but how to do I don't know, Please see Image attached with question for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
    LinearLayout layout2=(LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.relaGameZhaiGuoZi);
    layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  
    Button delbtn=new Button(this);  

    Button refreshbtn=new Button(this);  
    btn1.setText("Button1");  
    btn2.setText("Button2");  
    layout2.addView(delbtn);  
    layout2.addView(refreshbtn);
```

Then Add listener like this

> ```
> delbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>   @Override
>   public void onClick(View arg0) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       //del img
>   }
> });
> refreshbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>   @Override
>   public void onClick(View arg0) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       //refresh img
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: Can I will be able to use click event inside Touchlistener ? and also Imageview is not a viewGroup so How can I add button on it ?

Comment: use a RelativeLayout out side the imag and then you can add button in the RelativeLayout. and you can create your button   class TestButton  extends Button { } in your button Override   the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) function